# Cannot load file or assembly 'System.Runtime'

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, runtime

I have an Asp.Net 4.7 WebForms legacy application written in vb.net. To add Azure B2C authentication, I add OWIN middleware NuGet packages like this:

Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect

Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies

Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb

based on this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp

When I try to run the application, I get this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
> dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Here is the log:

Assembly manager loaded from: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe
--- A detailed error log follows.

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...
(Fully-specified)

LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Git Repos/InfoWeb/

LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Git Repos\InfoWeb\bin
Calling assembly : System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=4.2.29.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=....

===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.

LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Git Repos\InfoWeb\web.config

LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\dreznik\OneDrive - MyCompany\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config

LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.

LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 4.0.0.0 redirected to 4.1.1.0.

LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Runtime, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...

LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/17153f21/a2ffde83/System.Runtime.DLL.

LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/17153f21/a2ffde83/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.DLL.

LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Git Repos/InfoWeb/bin/System.Runtime.DLL.

LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Git Repos/InfoWeb/bin/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.DLL.

LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/17153f21/a2ffde83/System.Runtime.EXE.

LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/17153f21/a2ffde83/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.EXE.

LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Git Repos/InfoWeb/bin/System.Runtime.EXE.

LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Git Repos/InfoWeb/bin/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.EXE.

How can this be resolved? I have already tried to delete temporary Asp.Net files.

Answer (score 1):

You must check that **assemblyBinding** subsection inside **runtime** section of web.config file have correct value that define **System.Runtime**.

It must be something like this

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime
```

> 

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Code should be pasted as text, and formatted using Markdown. (The toolbar in the Stack Overflow editor can help you with this.) Code within images is harder to read, less accessible, can't be copied, and doesn't show up in relevant searches. Please [edit] your post to include the code as text; this will help you get better responses, and help prevent your answer from getting deleted.

Comment: @Reza Kia Thank you for your answer. Could you please also tell how I can determine the correct value? I do have already <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />

Comment: @DavidShochet The simplest and fastest way is to use nuget package manager to uninstall/reinstall or update component, it will update web.config with correct value

Comment: @RezaKia I tried it, and it restored it as it was. If I remove that redirect line, the error is gone... But I am afraid it may be breaking something else, right?